# Cannot call variables $_SESSION inside controller Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to call `$_SESSION` in laravel controller, because I placed laravel in a subfolder of another website so I need to get the session from another website. But because of I call `$_SESSION` inside controller, the redirect thing is not working and shown like this when I run `php artisan route:list`:

[image]

Anyone can help me to call $_SESSION from laravel controller?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Wrong

Please Do like this

Controller or model or route

Anywhere

```
 use Session;

$request->session()->put('`key`', 'value');

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

if (session('id') != null){
   echo 'Success'
 }
```

Or use the session() helper:

For Your Reference  https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session

Answer (score 1):

For Session's in Laravel you can refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session